# How do I add custom theme settings?

Tags: 8, forms

In my theme I have link to social network. So, I would like to have field in theme settings where administrator can put link what would be use in all place where is **{{link-social-network}}**.

```
<a href="{{link-social-network}}" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

I also read that theme settings default values can not be set in a theme's info.yml files.

The theme's **config/install/THEME.settings.yml** file should have that information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create new file and call it as `theme-settings.php` and add the following to it or even add this to THEME_NAME.theme file.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeSettings;
use Drupal\system\Form\ThemeSettingsForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form;

function THEME_NAME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['THEME_NAME_settings']['social_icon']['social_url'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Social Link'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('social_url', 'THEME_NAME'),
  );
}
```

Then you need to add the following to `THEME_NAME.theme` file.

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['social_url'] = theme_get_setting('social_url','THEME_NAME');
}
```

Then you can use it in the `twig` file.

```
<a href="{{ social_url }}" class="btn-social btn-outline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

To have a default value for the social url, you can include it in your  `config/install/THEME.settings.yml`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you a lot. This work perfect. How you lear to use use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeSettings;
use Drupal\system\Form\ThemeSettingsForm;
use Drupal\Core\Form;  I have problem with that..

Comment: Even am not pretty much sure about it.

Comment: If you want to have all theme settings available in twig you can union all to $variables. See my answer for details.

Comment: And you don't have to set `$theme_name` in `theme_get_setting('social_url');` because the current theme is the default value

Answer (score 4):

Additional to Suresh's answer: If you want to have all theme settings available in your twig template, use the following function:

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;
function _THEME_extend_variables(&$variables){
  // Add cachability metadata.
  $theme_name = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();
  $theme_settings = \Drupal::config($theme_name . '.settings');
  CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($variables)
    ->addCacheableDependency($theme_settings)
    ->applyTo($variables);
  // Union all theme setting variables to the twig template variables.
  $variables += $theme_settings->getOriginal();
}
```

and call it when ever you need to extend `$variables`:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // extend twig variables with theme settings
  _THEME_extend_variables($variables);
  // do fancy stuff
}
```

This is more or less copy pasted from [basic theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic).

Comment: This is interesting. Certainly I will try. Thank you for sharing your experience.